# Access is Denied error on jQuery ajax call to https URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ssl, cross-domain

I am trying to set up a client script to make an ajax call to a web service on a different domain, to make things more complicated the web service is HTTPS.  The service is MVC4 WebApi (REST).  The client script is also running from a HTTPS domain.  I am getting an "Access is denied" error when I try to make the call.  For example, I have a script running at https://domain_a.com/clientpage/script.js and making a call to https://domain_b.com/serviceapi/method/, the ajax error callback reports the Access is Denied error.  I took this exact scenario and tested without SSL in the mix, so http to http, and then the ajax call works fine, I also set $.support.cors = true, and also tried crossDomain: true in the ajax options.  Is this supposed to work with https, am I missing something, or will this simply not work?  Any suggestions?

Here is a sample of my ajax call:

```
$.support.cors = true;

$.ajax({
   url: requestURL,
   crossDomain: true,
   type: "GET",
   headers: { "Authentication": "user@domain.com:" + hashcode },
   data: "{}",
   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   dataType: "json",
   success: function (data) {
      alert("call succeeded");
   },
   error: function (response) {
      alert("call failed");
   }
});
```

jQuery version: 1.10.2
browser: IE9 (hoping this can work with multiple browsers: chrome, firefox, safari)
web service: MVC4 WebAPI .NET 4.5

UPDATE:

I did some more testing and ruled out the web service as the issue, it appears to be an issue with the underlying xmlhttprequest object or the browser.  I ran fiddler while testing the https to https scenario (fiddler is set to decrypt https traffic and I tested this) and there is no traffic whatsoever when I try to make the ajax call and it fails.  That leads me to believe its the browser.  Here's the list of scenarios I tested and the result:
http to http, same domains: success
http to http, different domains: success
https to https, same domains: success
https to https, different domains: fails.  <<--  I would expect this to be one of the most common scenarios for web service usage, some ISV makes a service available to customers who call it from a different domain, and they want to use SSL.

Comment: Have you made any changes to the web server?  Check out this article http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

Comment: Unless the service specifically supports CORS and different protocols, it doesn't matter what you set on the clientside, you'll still run in to the same origin policy that says protocols, ports and domains must match.

Comment: Thank you for the link to the article, I checked that out and tried it but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes when developing in a development environment, most companies don't dish out the money for a ssl cert and use a self signed cert which can cause the browser to throw up the big red screen that says warning and you have to continue.  In Chrome i know when you do this kind of stuff using an iframe, it crashes the iframe window unless i accept the cert during that session.

With that said, are you sure that domain_b.com has a valid ssl cert? if not have you accepted the SSL cert in your browser session?  You can test this by manually copying the URL from the ajax call, paste it in the window and visit it.  Once you accept the cert, it should start working.

You may see an image like this:

[image]

If so, click Proceed anyway

Comment: the ssl cert is valid on the domain I'm trying to call with ajax, it is a domain within my control, the cert is accepted as well.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't directly solve the issue of calling cross-domain on https, however I did come up with a workaround that was acceptable in my situation:  Instead of attempting to call cross-domain directly from the client I built a web service that sits between the client and server on the other domain.  The web service is on the same domain as the client and so the client can call this service without any trouble.  The web service then uses standard HTTP communications to send requests to the remote server and accept responses, the responses are then returned back to the client.  Basically the local web service acts like a sort of proxy between the clients and remote server.